# top align in html table?

Tags: html

how can i get the images and the content to the right to top align?
i tried valign="top" as you can see.

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr valign="top">
            <td valign="top"><img alt="" style="border: 0px solid;" src="/Portals/0/affiliates/NFL.png" /></td>
            <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
            <td valign="top" style="padding-left: 10px;"><strong><span class="cnt5_heading" style="color: #c00000;">NFL</span><br />
            </strong><span class="body_copy" valign="top">The official website for the National Football League. <a href="http://www.nfl.com/" target="_blank">Learn more &gt;&gt;</a></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
            <td valign="top"><img alt="" src="/Portals/0/affiliates/NFL_players_association.png" /></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td valign="top" style="padding-left: 10px;"><strong><span class="cnt5_heading" style="color: #c00000;">NFL Players Association</span><br />
            </strong><span class="body_copy" valign="top">"We, The National Football League Players Association ... Pay homage to our predecessors for their courage, sacrifice, and vision; ... Pledge to preserve and enhance the democratic involvement of our members; ... Confirm our willingness to do whatever is necessary for the betterment of our membership - To preserve our gains and achieve those goals not yet attained." <a href="http://www.nflplayers.com" target="_blank">Learn more &gt;&gt;</a></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
            <td valign="top"><img alt="" src="/Portals/0/affiliates/NFL_play_benfits.png" /></td>
            <td><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
            <td valign="top" style="padding-left: 10px;"><strong><span class="cnt5_heading" style="color: #c00000;">NFL Player Benefits</span></strong><br />
            <span class="body_copy">A Complete guide to the benefits available for NFL players. <a href="http://nfla.davidhenryagency.com/BenefitsampServices.aspx" target="_self">Learn more &gt;&gt;</a></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
            <td valign="top"><img alt="" src="/Portals/0/affiliates/NFL_hall_fame.png" /></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td valign="top" style="padding-left: 10px;"><strong><span class="cnt5_heading" style="color: #c00000;">Pro football Hall of Fame</span></strong><br />
            <span class="body_copy">The Mission of the Pro Football Hall of Fame is: To honor, preserve, educate and promote. <a href="http://www.profootballhof.com/default.aspx" target="_blank">Learn more &gt;&gt;</a></span><br />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Most of the attributes on the tags in the above code are the way things were done in the 1990s.  These attributes have long since been deprecated or defined as obsolete.  Anything that affects how items are displayed should be done using CSS. 
 And it should be done in the ``<style>`` section, not with individual ``style=`` attributes.

Answer (score 179, accepted):

Some CSS :

```css
table td, table td * {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: For ***tailwindcss*** users use: `align-top`

Answer (score 14):

```
<TABLE COLS="3" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <TR style="vertical-align:top">
        <TD>
            <!-- The log text-box -->
            <div style="height:800px; width:240px; border:1px solid #ccc; font:16px/26px Georgia, Garamond, Serif; overflow:auto;">
                Log:
            </div>
        </TD>
        <TD>
            <!-- The 2nd column -->
        </TD>
        <TD>
            <!-- The 3rd column -->
        </TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>
```