# HTML Table issues

Tags: html, html-table

I have a main table and then insert sub tables each td. Like below The problem is lets say I have:

```
<table id = "main>
<tr>
<th id = "header1">blah</td>
<th id = "header2">blah</td>
<th id = "header3">blah</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>
<table id = "sub1">
<tr><td headers='header1'>1</td></tr>
</table>
</td>
<td>
<table id = "sub2">
<tr><td headers='header2'>2</td></tr>
</table>
</td>
<td>
<table id = "sub3">
<tr><td headers='header3'>3</td></tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

now if sub1 has only 4 rows in it but sub 2 and 3 each have 100 rows the table keeps putting sub1 table in the middle of the rest of the table. How would i stop it from doing that?

Comment: `<th id = "header1">blah</td>` should be `<th id = "header1">blah</th>`. `<tr><td>` should be `<tr><td colspan="3">`.

Comment: Nested tables are terribad awful.  The lack of readability speaks for itself.  Use Divs.

Comment: This should help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673483/top-align-in-html-table

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: Nested tables are okay for nested tabular data.

Comment: If I had that situation, then Id write a simple HTML generator in javascript/c#.  That way u dont have to parse nested tables with your eyes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [top align in html table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673483/top-align-in-html-table)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<td valign="top">
```

You have to specify, where to align the content of **td**

Comment: Please use CSS instead: `td { vertical-align: top; }`

Answer (score 0):

Look in to [valign](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/th/valign)

```
<td valign='top'>
```

**Updated source**

```
<table id = "main>
<tr>
<th id = "header1">blah</td>
<th id = "header2">blah</td>
<th id = "header3">blah</td>
</tr>
<tr><td valign='top'>
<table id = "sub1">
<tr><td headers='header1'>1</td></tr>
</table>
</td>
<td>
<table id = "sub2">
<tr><td headers='header2'>2</td></tr>
</table>
</td>
<td>
<table id = "sub3">
<tr><td headers='header3'>3</td></tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the second table row (after the header row) opening tag `<tr style="vertical-align:top">`. That will work and there is no need for rowspan or colspan.

Answer (score 0):

If you are increasing/decreasing the no. of rows/cols in your tables, you may need to adust the same through rowspan and colspan properties. Also displaying text at the top of any cell needs `valign="top"` property